# Having multiple IOS developer accounts and can not create IOS distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, distribution, provisioning

I have 2 valid single IOS developer accounts and 1 mac book air. For better explaining my problem, I call my accounts as **account A** and **account B**. My problem is I can create developer and distribution certificates for account A. However I **can not create distribution certificate for account B with name of account B**. Account B's **distribution certificate takes name of account A' s name**. In order to create certificates, I follow  these steps: Open keychain access-->certificate assistant-->request certificate from a certificate authority-->entering account B name and mail address--> opening apple's developer page with account B login data and upload "certificate request file" to "create developer certificate" section and "create distribution certificate" section. "**Developer certificate**" successfully takes name from account B but "**distribution certificate**" takes account A' s name. I revoked certificates from account A and account B. I deleted certificates from keychain access and provisioning profiles from xcode's organizer and developer page but still I can not create distribution certificate with account B 's name. I have to send my application from account B because I created application at "**itunesconnect**" and I want to show developer name as account B. How can **account B 's distribution certificate** take name of **account B' s name** instead of **account A' s name** ? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account A and B don't have the same Team name? Because the Development Certificate is for a Team member and Distribution Cert. is for a Team. So, if you have the same Team name for both accounts, the Distribution Certificate will have the same name.

Comment: **Xcode's organizer** shows only Account A 's name under **TEAMS**. It looks like I have same team name for both accounts. How can I add account B's name  or create new TEAM member under **"TEAMS"**  in order to get distribution certificate with account B's name? Thank you very much for your help .

Comment: The original Team name is the name of your company and don't know if is possible to change it. But, try access [developer area](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter), click at "Your Account" menu and verify if is possible change the name. Sorry, but I don't have Enterprise Account, only Developer one.

Comment: My program membership name looks like same for both accounts but individual id s are different. This is why distribution certificate names are same. I will contact apple. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create extra keychains for certificates when you have multiple developer programs. Setup one set of certs per each keychain you add.

Xcode will only read certificates from the default keychain. So when you want to work with a set, copy the certs from your secondary keychain into your default(login) keychain. Then move them back when your are done.

It's a less than ideal solution, but it was an Apple provided solution.